# Edit Macro to create folder on desktop for any user

Tags: excel, vba, save, create-directory

I have a spreadsheet with a save button on every sheet. The buttons currently save the sheets onto any user's desktop as a PDF file. I was asked if I could possibly make the button create a new folder titled "BSInHouseAssets" on the desktop when doing this.  I am guessing that we would utilize MKdir at some point...but I need help.
Here is the current portion of the macro that saves the file.

```
Function SpecialFolderPath() As String

  Dim objWSHShell As Object
  Dim strSpecialFolderPath

  'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  ' Create a shell object
  Set objWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  ' Find out the path to the passed special folder,
  '  just change the "Desktop" for one of the other options
  SpecialFolderPath = objWSHShell.SpecialFolders("desktop")
  ' Clean up
  Set objWSHShell = Nothing
  Exit Function
ErrorHandler:

  MsgBox "Error finding " & strSpecialFolder, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Function
```

Comment: I succeeded creating the folder, thanks to your help, but I am having trouble saving the file to the folder. I updated the post above with the changes.

Comment: Please do not change your question. That invalidates the original question as well as the answers (and effort!) others have put into helping you. If you have a new question, ask a new question, with full information including HOW the code is not working.

Comment: And just by the way: That should NOT be "Exit Function" at the end. Your code won't work that way. It should be End Function.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir CreateObject("wscript.shell").specialfolders("desktop") & "\MyFolder"
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
strPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\"
strFolderName = "test1"
strFullPath = strPath & strFolderName & "\"

    If Dir(strPath & strFolderName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir strFullPath
    End If

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFullPath & "workbookname1", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Comment: that will not create the folder on the *current user*'s desktop

Comment: Updated to take current user in to account

Comment: This was great for creating the folder, thank you. For some reason, it's not saving the document in that folder, though.

Comment: Where is it saving? Are you getting any errors? On the off chance, try adding .xlsm to the file name. Also just seeing your edited code, have you declared the path strings? Add \ after desktop in strPath.